# Symfony 5.1 nested forms with ArrayCollection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, symfony-forms

I have an employee entity, a society entity and a site entity,

A society can have several sites (OneToMany),
The employee has a form. Inside, we have the choice of society.

I would like to nest the Site FormType in that of society.
So when I choose a society under EmployeeForm, it only suggests sites linked to society.
Hope I am clear. I followed the symfony documentation on how to embed an ArrayCollection.

https://symfony.com/doc/5.1/form/form_collections.html
and I looked https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

I'm not sure which is the best approach ?

I still get the error

> The object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be
> converted to a string

and I am unable in SocietyForm to isolate the "name" attribute of each Site. I don't want a collection, but a list of name (string).

---

**EmployeeType**

```
class EmployeeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', NULL, [
                'label' => 'Nom',
            ])
            ->add('firstname', NULL, [
                'label' => 'Prénom',
            ])
            ->add('societe', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => 'Société',
                'class' => RefSociety::class,
                'choice_label' => 'Name',
            ])
            ->add('site', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => 'Site',
                'class' => RefSociety::class,
                'choice_label' => 'refSites'
            ])

        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Employee::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

---

**RefSocietyType**

```
class RefSocietyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('Name', NULL, [
                'label' => 'Nom de société'
            ])
            ->add('refSites', CollectionType::class, array(
                'type' => RefSiteType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ))   
            ->add('Adress', NULL, [
                'label' => 'Adresse'
            ])
            ->add('PostalCode', NULL, [
                'label' => 'Code postal'
            ])
            ->add('Country', NULL, [
                'label' => 'Pays'
            ])
            ->add('City', NULL, [
                'label' => 'Ville'
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-radius'],
                'label' => 'Sauvegarder'
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => RefSociety::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

---

**RefSiteType**

```
class RefSiteType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('name')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => RefSite::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

---

**index.html.twig**

```
{ form_start(employeeForm) }}
{{form_row(employeeForm.name, {'attr' : {'class' : ""} }) }}
{{form_row(employeeForm.firstname, {'attr' : {'class' : ""} }) }}
{{form_row(employeeForm.societe) }}
<ul class="sites">
   {% for site in employeeForm.refSites %}
      <li>{{ form_row(site.name) }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
{{ form_end(employeeForm) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   ->add('site', EntityType::class, [
        'label' => 'Site',
        'class' => RefSociety::class,
        'choice_label' => 'refSites'
    ])
```

`'choice_label' => 'refSites'` means that the method getRefSites() are called by `PropertyAccessor` to get a label name, so the method `getRefSites` returns the collection (because one to many), but the label must be a string.

Maybe should you use `'choice_label' => 'name'` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, using `'choice_label' => 'name'` gives me a drop down list of society names. It will look for name instead of refSites. But actually, I have to find a way to convert this collection. I found a cool [symfony feature](https://symfony.com/doc/5.1/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms) that maybe could help here, the FormEvent, but nothing for sure yet. Thank you for your reply !

Comment: `refSites` is a collection, how the collection should be displayed?  You also can use `choice_label` as a function https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-label

Comment: Thank you very much, this is an interesting solution, but I don't think which one is suitable for my use case. I have to choose the sites in relation to the company previously selected. It is in this sense that the FormEvent seems to me to be relevant. I am still blocked because the site field still does not display a list.

Comment: FormEvent (Post submit) is suitable to validate the submitting data, but for displaying, you should render all list and hide not relevant by js or get choice values by ajax

Comment: I followed this part of the documentation:
https://symfony.com/doc/5.1/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms
You are right, I added ajax, with the **POST_SUBMIT** and **PRE_SET_DATA**, My Site list still does not appear, I feel that I am close to success however,

Comment: Hello, I am writing this message to follow up on those who will read this, I have opened another topic to my problem, oriented towards the FORM EVENT, which corresponds more to my problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66419561/symfony-5-1-dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms-no-display