# Symfony 5.1 Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms - No display

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm embarking on this new post because despite a lot of research I'm stuck.

I have three entities.

Employee -> ManyToOne -> RefSociety

Employee -> ManyToOne -> RefSite

RefSociety -> OnToMany -> RefSite

RefSociety -> OnToMany -> Employee

RefSite -> OnToMany -> Employee

RefSite -> ManyToOne -> RefSociety

I am using the symfony documentation from FormEvent ; https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

I want that in my Employee form, when I select a society, then, it only offers me the sites attached to this society.

Here is what I have already done. I have tried a lot of different ways. When I manually pass a SocietyId, then it recognizes it and shows me the desired sites.

Also I don't think it's the JavaScript side that is blocking. Do you have an idea ?

**EmployeeType.php**

```
class EmployeeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('societe', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => RefSociety::class,
                'placeholder' => 'Sélectionnez votre société',
                'mapped' => false,
            ])
        ;
        
        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, ?RefSociety $society)
        {
            $sites = null === $society ? [] : $society->getSites();

            $form->add('site', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => RefSite::class,
                'placeholder' => 'Sélectionnez votre site',
                'choices' => $sites,
            ]);
        };
        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier)
            {
                $data = $event->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getSociete());
            }
        );
        $builder->get('societe')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier)
            {
                $society = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $society);
            }
        );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Employee::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**index.html.twig**

```
{{ form_start(employeeForm) }}
   {{form_row(employeeForm.societe) }}
   {{form_row(employeeForm.site) }}
{{ form_end(employeeForm) }}

   <script>
        var $society = $('#employee_societe');
        $society.change(function () {
            var $employeeForm = $(this).closest('employeeForm');
            var data = {};
            data[$society.attr('name')] = $society.val();
            //console.log(data)
            $.ajax({
                url: $employeeForm.attr('action'),
                type: $employeeForm.attr('method'),
                data: data,
                success: function (html) {
                    //console.log(data)
                    $('#employee_site').replaceWith(
                        $(html).find('#employee_site')
                    );
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What's in your ajax request and what do you receive in the server's response ?

Comment: Hello jona303, the ajax request returns the id corresponding to the scoiety in my `console.log(data)`, `{...} "employee[societe]": "6"`

Regarding the server response to the $society, it's a `[ ]`, so I think it can't get society back, but it should

Comment: Hello, for information I managed to solve my problem but not in the best way. Indeed, I got the list of sites by society in my controller that I put in an **array []**, I then sent this to my view, then using **Ajax**, I indicated dynamically those which must be displayed according to the choice of the society. If you are stuck like me do not hesitate to contact me.

If anyone has the solution using **FormEvent**, I would love to know about it, thanks !